# How do you refresh an array at iteration of loop in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

For a given array, I want to compute products always leaving one value out. For example, for input `[1, 2, 3, 4]` I want output `[2*3*4, 1*3*4, 1*2*4, 1*2*3]`, i.e., `[24, 12, 8, 6]`.

```
def array_product(array)
  arr_lgth=array.length
  array_d=array.dup 
  sum=[]
  itr=0

  while itr<(arr_lgth)
    p itr
    p array

    array[itr]=1
    sum << array.reduce(1,:*); 
    array=array_d

    itr+=1
  end

  return sum
end

array_product([1,2,3,4])
```

As I track the iteration and array, I get the following results that I do not understand:

```
0
[1, 2, 3, 4]
1
[1, 2, 3, 4]
2
[1, 1, 3, 4]
3
[1, 1, 1, 4]
```

Shouldn't the array be assigned the duplicate values at the end of each while loop iteration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot going on in this code for what should be a simple problem. One of the strengths of Ruby is being able to express a simple solution to this exact problem. I think what you're trying to do comes out as:

```
def array_product(array)
  # Convert each index in the array...
  array.each_index.map do |i|
    # ...into a copy of the array with that index set as 1...
    array.each_with_index.map do |a, j|
      i == j ? 1 : a
    end.reduce(1, :*) # ...multiplied together.
  end
end
```

It's rare to see conventional `for` loops, use of iterator-like variables and such in Ruby because there's a wealth of tools in the [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Enumerable.html) library that makes them mostly obsolete.

The key here is to use tools like `map` whenever possible in preference to `dup` and some hammering around with the data using index variables. The `map` function is key for when you need a 1:1 "mapping" of the original data into an array of identical length where you get to decide how to handle each element individually.

This code produces:

```
array_product([ 1, 2, 3 ])
# => [6, 3, 2]
```

Comment: In this format (i == j ? 1 : a) are you saying if index i = index j, assign 1 to a, as the value of the array? Hope I am making sense, very new to ruby, thanks!

Comment: `reduce(:*)` works as well. And I think their idea of duplicating the array and writing a 1 into it is better than this, they just didn't do it right.

Comment: @Abid That ternary returns either `1` or `a` depending on the equivalence of `i == j`. The way `map` works is whatever value you return in the block is what ends up populating that spot in the remapped array, so yes, basically it assigns that to the value in the new array.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you want to find the product of each combination of three numbers.

```
[1,2,3,4].combination(3).map{|c| c.reduce(:*)}
```

Comment: Ah, nice! One issue, though: Unlike our other solutions which never do empty products, yours does. When the array has only one element, you compute `[nil]` instead of `[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake is that you duplicate the given array only once. For the first index you then work with the given array, and then you set `array=array_d` and from then on *for all remaining indexes* you're working on *that duplicate* the whole time, writing more and more `1`s into it.

The simplest way to fix it is to use `array=array_d.dup` there instead, i.e., just append `.dup` there. Then you don't work on the same array over and over again but instead always reset to the original (duplicated) values as you intended.

But it's better to just make a duplicate right *before* the calculation of each product, and use that fresh duplicate to compute the product. So change your inner part to this:

```
    array_d = array.dup 
    array_d[itr] = 1
    sum << array_d.reduce(:*)
```

The whole method made rubyish:

```
def array_product(array)
  array.each_index.map do |i|
    dup = array.dup
    dup[i] = 1
    dup.reduce(:*)
  end
end
```

By the way, note that you don't need to initialize `reduce` with `1`.

Oh and in case your array doesn't have zeros, you could also just compute the product of *all* numbers *once* and then divide it by each number. That's much faster:

```
def array_product(array)
  p = array.reduce(:*)
  array.map { |x| p / x }
end
```